# How do I get a collection of documents all at once using an array of IDs using firebase?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to build a React 16.13.0 application with firebase.  I have the following method, in which I want to get a collection of documents all at once using an array of IDs ...

```
async acceptMissions(userId: string, missionId: string[]) {
    const collection = this.getCollection("organizations").doc("1").collection("missions");
    let docs;
    try {
      docs = await collection.getAll(...missionIds).get();
```

However, the line

```
const collection = this.getCollection("organizations").doc("1").collection("missions");
```

dies with the error

```
TypeScript error in /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/resilience-app/src/app/model/User.ts(243,31):
Property 'getAll' does not exist on type 'CollectionReference<DocumentData>'.  TS2339
```

What's the proper way of getting a collection of documents all at once?

Answer (score 0):

[getAll()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Firestore.html#getAll) is a method on the Firestore object, and **only** for server SDKs, such as nodejs.  It's not available at all on client SDKs.

If you have an array of IDs to fetch from a collection, you will have to build a DocumentReference to each one and call get() on all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have <= 10 IDs you want to fetch you could use the following query:

```
db.collection("organizations").doc("1").collection("missions")
    .where("__name__", "in", ["docid1", "docid2", ... "docid10"]
    .get()
```

`__name__` is the reserved name the backend uses for the document ID. As stated above `in` query clauses can have a maximum of 10 values.